# "der Ring des Nibelungen" vs "der Ring der Nibelungen"

Tags: article, literature

Warum ist es "der Ring *des* Nibelungen" und nicht "der Ring *der* Nibelungen", d.h. Genitiv Plural?

Comment: Bis zu deiner Frage hätte ich geschworen, es heiße "Ring *der* Nibelungen"...

Comment: The confusion crosses language boundaries, as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eN5dAQLYYrs

Answer (score 13):

Kurz: Der Zwerg Alberich aus dem Volk der Nibelungen schmiedet sich aus dem Rheingold einen Ring - den Ring **des Nibelungen [Alberich]**.

Da der Ring am Ende wieder in den Rhein kommt, statt zB in der Familie weitergegeben zu werden, erübrigt sich der Plural. Außerdem ist das ganze ja ein *Titel* von Richard Wagner.

Wikipedia:

> Das Werk beginnt mit einem etwa vierminütigen Vorspiel (136 Takte), in dem sich aus einem tiefen Es-Dur-Akkord Themen des wogenden Rheins entwickeln. Erst danach beginnt die eigentliche Handlung, in der zunächst die Rheintöchter Floßhilde, Wellgunde und Woglinde auftreten. Diese sind naive Naturwesen, die einen zauberhaften Schatz besitzen und in der Tiefe des Flusses hüten – das Rheingold. Dieser Schatz verliert aber seinen unschuldigen Charakter und verhilft zu endloser Macht, wenn sein Besitzer der Liebe abschwört und einen Ring aus dem Gold schmiedet (Zitat: „Nur wer der Minne Macht entsagt, nur wer der Liebe Lust verjagt, nur der erzielt sich den Zauber, zum Reif zu zwingen das Gold“).
>
> Dem Zwerg Alberich vom Volk der Nibelungen gelingt ebendies (darum: Der Ring des Nibelungen), nachdem die Rheintöchter sein Liebesbegehren verschmäht haben und Alberich in maßloser Wut das Gold raubt.

<sub>Um die Deklination - insbesondere die Einzahl - des Wortes "Nibelungen" scheint Nibelung zu herrschen. Wiktionary schlägt *Nibelung* im 1. Fall Sg. und sonst *Nibelungen* vor, während der Duden ein Pluraletantum darin sieht. Im Grimm findet sich jedoch ein Eintrag zu *Nibelung*, dem Sohn des Nebels [usw.](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN04908#XGN04908) Überdies findet sich im selben Eintrag eine Genitivbildung mit "(e)s". Eine (Online-)Suche im Originaltext bestätigte weder "Nibelung" noch "Nibelunge".</sub>

Comment: Vielleicht kannst du noch die [Deklination des Wortes *Nibelung*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nibelung) erwähnen. Ich für meinen Teil finde diese nämlich etwas merkwürdig und hätte eher *der Nibelung*, Gen. *des Nibelungs* erwartet.